# Stored Procedure does not work when called but prepared Statement does

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

my problem is, that in mysql I created a stored procedure. Im trying to call this procedure through my java-code.

> I dont get any exception but the db is not affected. If I make the
>   same Statement through a preparedstatement everything works just fine.
>   And if i call the procedure manuallys in the workbench it works too.

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`PROCEDURE `delete`(IN id INT(11))
BEGIN SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0; Delete from sender where id = id; 
END
```

**Call in Code**

```
        public void deleteSender(int id){
        CallableStatement cStmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pStmt_2 = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/info", "root","");

String call = "{call delete(?)}";
cStmt = connection.prepareCall(call);
cStmt.setInt(1, id);
boolean b = cStmt.execute();


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

As prepared Statement:

    public void deleteSender(int id){

        CallableStatement cStmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pStmt_2 = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/info", "root","");

            pStmt = connection.prepareStatement("Delete from sender where id="+id);
            pStmt_2 = connection.prepareStatement("Delete from  table2 where sender_id="+id);

            boolean b = pStmt.execute();
            boolean b_2 = pStmt_2.execute();
            if(b == false || b_2 == false){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data deleted");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: 1. You are not getting exceptions in the first section *because you do not seem to be handling them* (same goes for the second segment). 2. Your second section is not a prepared statement, you are still concatenating the `id` value to the string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but even if i catch the exception with a syso or something it doesnt even get there but in debug Mode everything got called correctly. The second code works the same if i set the values as a real prepared statement so either way it works... just the callable does not

Answer (score 0):

In the stored procedure, avoid naming its parameters as the name of its columns. Rename the input parameter `id` by `_id` (for example), leaving your stored procedure as follows:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delete`(IN _id INT(11))
BEGIN
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES := 0;
    DELETE FROM sender WHERE id = _id; 
END;
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. It seems like Im pretty close, I changed the input-parameter as you suggested but now I get a mysql-syntax error. He takes the right id but the error says ´check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delete(1717)'.... But I cant fiind any syntax error :S